# Lauter technische Spielereien oder Lautere technische Spielereien

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

Ich habe eine Frage bezüglich der Sätze unten.

*Die Fernseher sind schlechter geworden. **Lauter** technische Spielereien, die nach kurzer Zeit kaputtgehen.*

Warum nutzt man eigentlich *lauter* statt *lautere*? [Lauter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lauter_anstaendig_unverdorben) ist ja ein Adjektiv, und als solches muss dekliniert werden, oder?

Ich lese gerne die Antworten auch auf English.

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lauter_viel_viele

Comment: Es gibt auch lautere Freunde, also ehrliche. Allerdings sind lautere technische Spielereien nicht gut vorstellbar.

Comment: Es gibt auch laute Freunde und laute technische Spielereien. Diese Hinweise fehlen der Antwort im Duplikat.